# Get bounds of geocoder address

Tags: android, geocoding

On ios and other platforms geocoder gives back latitude, longitude and a "suggested radius" for that address.

F.E. if you search "Rome" it give an approx radius of city as region radius. If you search a single street it gives a smaller one.

Is there a way to get this radius using android sdk?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and there currently is not a bounds field in the Address object. [This tutorial should help you.](http://bricolsoftconsulting.com/2011/11/04/perfect-geocoding-zoom-part-1/) Also see [the new Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

To work with Google Maps Android v2 using GeocoderPlus library:

```
    public void updateMapToAddress (GeocoderPlusAddress foundAddress) {
       LatLng addressSouthWest = new LatLng(foundAddress.getViewPort().getSouthWest().getLatitude(), 
             foundAddress.getViewPort().getSouthWest().getLongitude());
       LatLng addressNorthEast = new LatLng(foundAddress.getViewPort().getNorthEast().getLatitude(), 
             foundAddress.getViewPort().getNorthEast().getLongitude());

       LatLngBounds addressBounds = new LatLngBounds(addressSouthWest, addressNorthEast);
       CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(addressBounds, 0);

       map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
    }
```